# add column to positive or negative sequence in r

Tags: r

I want to add negative or positive sequences in my column. Indeed per ID if col_int==1 put a negative sequence on the lines before the value 1 and put a negative sequence on the lines after.

```
dfs <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("ID1",11),rep("ID2",4), rep("ID3",6)) , col_int=c(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,0,0,0),c(0,0,1,0,1,1) )) dfs_out <- dfs %>% mutate(col_out = c(c(seq(-5,-1)),1,c(seq(1,5)), c(1,1,2,3),c(-2,-1,1,1,2,3)))
```

Comment: dfs <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("ID1",11),rep("ID2",4), rep("ID3",6)) ,
                  col_int=c(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,0,0,0),c(0,0,1,0,1,1) ))


dfs_out <- dfs %>%
mutate(col_out = c(c(seq(-5,-1)),1,c(seq(1,5)), c(1,1,2,3),c(-2,-1,1,1,2,3)))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(dplyr)# version>= 1.1.0
 dfs_out %>% 
  mutate(col_out2 = (row_number() - match(1, col_int)) + 
    (col_int == 1 & !duplicated(col_int)), .by = ID)
```

-output

```
    ID col_int col_out col_out2
1  ID1       0      -5       -5
2  ID1       0      -4       -4
3  ID1       0      -3       -3
4  ID1       0      -2       -2
5  ID1       0      -1       -1
6  ID1       1       1        1
7  ID1       0       1        1
8  ID1       0       2        2
9  ID1       0       3        3
10 ID1       0       4        4
11 ID1       0       5        5
12 ID2       1       1        1
13 ID2       0       1        1
14 ID2       0       2        2
15 ID2       0       3        3
16 ID3       0      -2       -2
17 ID3       0      -1       -1
18 ID3       1       1        1
19 ID3       0       1        1
20 ID3       1       2        2
21 ID3       1       3        3
```